# Configuration changes even after adding ViewModel : Android Architecture Component

Tags: android, viewmodel

I've added a **ViewModel** class from the **lifecycle** architecture library. But it does not work in my code. What did I do wrong. I'm new to ViewModel Arch Component of android.

Here is my code:

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"

}
```

ViewModel:

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class NameViewModel extends ViewModel {

// Create a LiveData with a String
private MutableLiveData<String> mCurrentName;

public MutableLiveData<String> getmCurrentName() {
    if (mCurrentName == null) {
        mCurrentName = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }
    return mCurrentName;
}

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.Observer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NameViewModel nameViewModel;

private TextView lblText;
private EditText txtValue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lblText = findViewById(R.id.textview);
    txtValue = findViewById(R.id.editText);

    final Observer<String> nameObserver = new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String data) {

            lblText.setText(data);

        }
    };

    nameViewModel.getmCurrentName().observe(this, nameObserver);

    txtValue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence value, int start, int before, int count) {
            nameViewModel.getmCurrentName().setValue(value.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

  }
}
```

Am I missing something which is necessary?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Where do you instantiate `nameViewModel` ?

Comment: I thought it came from LiveData.. is the above implementation wrong?

Comment: Yes,try to put this code in `onCreate` method      `nameViewModel= ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity(), null).get(NameViewModel.class);`

Comment: I copy-pasted your code at first line after setContentView(...) , but getActivity() shows in red. it says "Cannot Resolve Method getActivity()" Other things are fine. What is null there?

Comment: Oh sorry you are in activity, so pass `this` instead,`this` is the lifecycle owner and null is `factory`, which I think you don't need now.

Comment: Okay. What is factory BTW.

Comment: Hey, it works, although I removed null and kept only "this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your `onCreate` method

```
nameViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, null).get(NameViewModel.class);
```

And refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.Factory) and [this](https://medium.com/@dpreussler/add-the-new-viewmodel-to-your-mvvm-36bfea86b159) links for more info about `ViewModelProvider.Factory`

Comment: Thank you, It works :) And thanks for the links,  I really appreciate it..